# Why use JLE instead of JL?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction

I wrote the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%i",i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using `gcc test.c -o test.o`, then disassembled it using `objdump -d -Mintel test.o`. The assembly code I got (at least the relevant part) is the following:

```
0804840c <main>:
 804840c:   55                      push   ebp
 804840d:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 804840f:   83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
 8048412:   83 ec 20                sub    esp,0x20
 8048415:   c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x0
 804841c:   00 
 804841d:   eb 19                   jmp    8048438 <main+0x2c>           
 804841f:   8b 44 24 1c             mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
 8048423:   89 44 24 04             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
 8048427:   c7 04 24 e8 84 04 08    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x80484e8
 804842e:   e8 bd fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <printf@plt>
 8048433:   83 44 24 1c 01          add    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x1
 8048438:   83 7c 24 1c 03          cmp    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x3
 804843d:   7e e0                   jle    804841f <main+0x13>
 804843f:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
 8048444:   c9                      leave  
 8048445:   c3                      ret
```

I noticed that, although my compare operation was `i < 4`, the assembly code is (after disassembly) `i <= 3`. Why does that happen? Why would it use `JLE` instead of `JL`?

Comment: That's probably code-gen that encourages a subsequent optimization, like loop unrolling.  Which didn't happen, avoid looking at unoptimized code.

Comment: This is actually a gcc code generation choice (you need to dig into the tree representation of the code), but it turns a `var < N` test into a range test of [MinVar .. N - 1], which is where the 3 comes from. If it's of any comfort clang tests for 4, but puts the test *at the start of the loop*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loops that count upwards, and have constant limit, are very common. The compiler has two options to implement the check for loop termination - `JLE` and `JL`. While the two ways seem absolutely equivalent, consider the following.

As you can see in the disassembly listing, the constant (`3` in your case) is encoded in 1 byte. If your loop counted to 256 instead of 4, it would be [impossible](http://intel80386.com/386htm/Cmp.htm) to use such an efficient encoding for the `CMP` instruction, and the compiler would have to use a "larger" encoding. So `JLE` provides a marginal improvement in code density (which is ultimately good for performance because of caching).

Answer (score 1):

It would JLE because it shifted the value by one.

```
if (x < 4) {
  // ran when x is 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, ... MIN_INT.
}
```

is logically equivalent to

```
if (x <= 3) {
  // ran when x is 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, ... MIN_INT.
}
```

Why the compiler chose one internal representation over another is often a matter of optimization, but really it is hard to know if optimization was the true driver.  In any case, functional equivalents like this is the reason why back-mapping isn't 100% accurate.  There are many ways to write a condition that has the same effect over the same inputs.